# Disable end meeting option in BigBlueButton

Tags: bigbluebutton

I have searched for a day almost and couldn't find anything helpful from both the official BBB docs and google.

I have some recurring calendar events setup and I am using bigbluebutton for the video conferencing. Since the meeting is recurring I don't want any one to end the meeting rather just leave the meeting. So my question here is there any way to disable the `End meeting` option from BBB client.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Only `moderator` users have "end meeting" option and if you give people of your events the join url of a `viewer (attendee)` and you join as a `moderator`, then no body else would have this option.
You can check it out here:
[API Mate](https://mconf.github.io/api-mate/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am aware of that and I don't want moderator to end the meeting by any chance

Comment: I think it's not an option in bigbluebutton and if you want sth like that, you should develop the code for it yourself. I can help you with that

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py` you can set the value of `allowLogout` to `false` then no one (neither viewers nor moderators) would be able to logout with buttons (Leave meeting / End meeting)